# pandas name of aggregate lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a df that is like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : np.random.normal(10, 1, 1000),
                   'col2' : np.random.normal(10, 1, 1000), 
                   'col3' : np.random.normal(10, 1, 1000), })
```

I would like to calculate lambda function on the df. For example:

```
df.agg([lambda x: x[-260:].mean() - x[-260:].std(), 
        lambda x: x[-360:].mean() - x[-360:].std(),
        lambda x: x[-100:].mean() - x[-100:].std()]
        )
```

I get as a result:

```
    col1    col2    col3
<lambda>    8.931537    9.150050    9.040931
<lambda>    8.930975    9.112472    9.012097
<lambda>    8.914012    9.169566    8.980311
```

but how to rename the line  ? they have the same name

name lambda fonction after agg function

Answer (score 0):

You can use named functions:

```
def A(x):
    return x[-260:].mean() - x[-260:].std()

def B(x):
    return x[-360:].mean() - x[-360:].std()

def C(x):
    return x[-100:].mean() - x[-100:].std()

df.agg([A, B, C])
```

Otherwise just [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
df.agg([lambda x: x[-260:].mean() - x[-260:].std(), 
        lambda x: x[-360:].mean() - x[-360:].std(),
        lambda x: x[-100:].mean() - x[-100:].std()]
      ).set_axis(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Output:

```
       col1      col2      col3
A  9.036280  8.849999  9.030373
B  8.967197  8.834413  9.027176
C  9.027716  8.935721  8.956289
```

Comment: thanks ! it works with set_axis but how to name the function ???

Comment: @jacques I updated the answer with an example